# Features needed when building a ORM with PHP?

Tags: php, orm

I have never really appreciated ORM's so I think that the only way to remedy this is to build a basic one myself so I can see what all the hubbub is. So with that in mind, what are the basic features I would need to include to make a semi-usable ORM?

As far as I can tell, it would basically need to work like this for the end programmer:

```
/*
 * Create a user
 */
$user = new User();
$user->name = 'Joe';
$user->email = 'joe@aol.com';
$user->save();
unset($user);

/*
 * Create a game
 */
$game = new Game();
$game->name = 'soccer';
$game->save();

/*
 * Set all users as players
 */
$users = ORM::factory('users');
$users = $users->findAll();
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    $user->setGame($game);
    $user->save();
}
unset($users);

/*
 * Get all games and show all users
 */
$games = ORM::factory('games')->findAll();
foreach( $games as $game ) {
    print $game->name;
    print 'Users in game:';
    foreach( $game->users as $user ) {
        print $user->name;
    }
}
```

Each model class would extend the ORM class which would have all the basic methods

- find($id)
- findAll($where)
- save()

Other usefull features would be things like:

- Able to request rows with a certain id `User::find(34)`
- Able to limit result rows with WHERE like options
- Able to tie one row object to many rows from another table. (1 to many)
- Query building so that the SQL was written automatically.

Could anyone else tell me what I would need. I've been looking at some of the libraries like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org), [EZPDO](http://www.ezpdo.net), [dORM](http://www.getdorm.com), and [KohanaPHP](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm) but I can't seem to find a library that is easy to digest to figure out what the feature list would need to be to tackle this project.

I found an [image detailing](http://learn.kohanaphp.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/ruby-on-rails-data-relationships.png) some of ruby's offerings and some more info on the [IgnitedRecord](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/IgnitedRecord/IgnitedRecord_Manual) Project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of basic and extended features ORM is supposed to have:
http://madgeek.com/Articles/ORMapping/EN/mapping.htm

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that you can handle many to many relationships.

Comment: What would an example of this be?

Comment: You might have a DB model where a user can belong to more than one game - so, in the DB you wouldn't have a single FOREIGN KEY on the user, you'd have a join table.

ORM should handle this by offering a user->getAllGames() or something similar.

Also to think about:

1. Offer ability to eager or lazy load associated games when loading a user
2. Offer ability to save all associated games when saving a user.