# Could someone give a perfect example of a basic "user" object system, using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop, pdo

What I'd like is to see the ideal framework for a system which has a group of objects (ie User) whereby the data is contained in a database. I've been advised to have a User class and a UserMapper class and this is my understanding of  how it should look:

**user.class.php**

```
/* The class for constructing any user's information
 */

    class User {

        protected $userId, $email, $userGroup;

        protected function getEmail() {
            return $this->email;
        }

        protected function getUserId() {
            return $this->userId;
        }


        public function __construct($userId, $email, $userGroup) {
            $this->userId = $userId;
            $this->email = $email;
            $this->userGroup = $userGroup;
        }

    }

    class UserMapper {
        // database connection
        private $db;

        public function __construct($db)
        {
            $this->db = $db;
        }

        public function findByUserId ($userId) {
            $userObject = new User();
            $q = $this->db->prepare("SELECT userId, email, userGroup FROM user WHERE userId = :userId");
            $q->bindValue(":userId", $id);
            $q->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_INTO, $userObject);
            $q->execute();
            $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_INTO);
            return $userObject;

        }
    }   
?>
```

**main.php**

```
<?php  
    include user.class.php;
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
    $getUser = new UserMapper($dbh);
    $user = $getUser->findByUserId(41);
    echo $user->getEmail();
?>
```

But this seems a bit messy in terms of the main.php side. Can I not make one PDO object and have that defined in all of my scripts? As well as a UserMapper object? Or do every time I want to get a user from the database do I need to make a NEW userMapper object, then do findByUserId (as above). Or is there a simpler way to doing this?

If I wanted to call a UserGroup object within the class User, how would I do this? (This would also need to connect to the database through PDO). To do the following seems messy:

```
<?php
       $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $getUserGroup = new UserGroupMapper($dbh);
        $userGroup = $getUserGroupMapper->findByUserId($this->userGroup);
?>
```

Comment: Great question tom! You are essentially trying to build your own ORM. I'd suggest checking out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664932/features-needed-when-building-a-orm-with-php/1664939#1664939 and some good discussion on Reddit on the topic: http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/164r3w/to_orm_or_not_to_orm/

Comment: Why don't you declare one from each at top of your `main.php` and then use them to the rest of your script?

Answer (score 1):

one thing that i can think of is making this class a singleton, and create the $user above the declaration of the class, so whenever you include this class you'll have that user object.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I not make one PDO object and have that defined in all of my
>   scripts? As well as a UserMapper object?

#### You're actually looking for a Front Controller.

That is, in order to avoid the same instantiation of the same classes, you should have prepared them. Most people usually do this in `bootstrap.php`, that "tweaks" all required dependencies.

But a front controller implementation also includes a dispatcher and a router. I won't go deep into this, but focus on the problem you're trying to solve instead.

#### Factory pattern

It basically abstracts instantiation logic. The benefits are: 1) you can delay object instantiation 2) You avoid global state, which is bad for unit-testing. The simplified version of it would look like as:

```
class UserFactory
{
   private $pdo;

   private $cache = array();

   public function __construct($pdo)
   {
      $this->pdo = $pdo;
   }

   public function build($mapper)
   {
      if (isset($this->cache[$mapper])) {
         return $this->cache[$mapper];
      } else {
         // Inject an instance into a mapper
         $instance = new $mapper($this->pdo);
         // Save the state into a cache
         $this->cache[get_class($instance)] = $instance;
         return $instance;
      }
   }
}
```

#### And finally

A very simplified version of bootstrap-er would look like as,

```
<?php

/* File : bootstrap.php */

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));

// Include here UserFactory class
$userFactory = new UserFactory($dbh);

// Its kinda ready to be used
```

You would simply include in all scripts that need to access Users

```
<?php

/* File: main.php */
include(__DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php');

$getUser = $userFactory->build('UserMapper');
$user    = $getUser->findByUserId(41);

echo $user->getEmail();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use FETCH_CLASS instead and you don't need a userMapper just extend PDO then set the right fetch mode all in one class.

Don't forget to make the class definition available or use an autoloader

```
$this->statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,"className");
```

FETCH_PROPS_LATE  is there to get the constructor fired first in your class But you don't need a constructor in your case so just lose it. If you decide to keep it though than you should take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127693/pdo-using-pdofetch-props-late-and-construct-call) first.

Hope this helps good luck